# when i am using android studio getting this error "The environment variable JAVA_HOME does not point to valid jvm installation"

Tags: java, android-studio

When I start Android Studio, I get this error:

> The environment variable JAVA_HOME does not point to a valid JVM installation.

My `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;`.

Comment: You need to install Java 8 JDK it currently isn't installed on the system

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon from the end of the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. That variable can only point to one place; it's not like `PATH` which separates folders with semicolons.

You also need to remove the `bin` part; the variable should point to the root of the JDK installation.

Answer (score 0):

I dont use system environment in my configurations.

In User variables set **JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65**

In User variables set **JDK_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin**

In User variables add current **PATH = %JDK_HOME%;%JAVA_HOME%;..your current path..**

There is no path about java in system variables...

I solved this problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set **JAVA_HOME** under **System variables** instead of adding it User variables This has worked for me.